# SCORM 2004 LMS Testing

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

On the ADL website (http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-3rd/#tab-resources) there is the test suite to test for the SCORM 2004 4th conformance. But when I installed it and launched to start a test it gives no click-able "New LMS Conformance Test" button, so can't start a new LMS test. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check you Java version. If it's above 7 update 21 I suggest you delete it and install version 6 last update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install latest version of java. And also jvm

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the latest JRE.

The 4th Ed Test Suite was developed using Java 6 and IE7.

You will need to get back to those. Usually the best way is with a VM with Windows XP sp 2 installed on it. Check the readme that comes with the install, it'll give you the compatible Java and Browser versions.

Comment: BTW, good source for WinXP/IE7 virtual machines (free, legal, very fast download) is Microsoft's own website http://www.modern.ie/